# How to make vertical tabs with React

Tags: reactjs, vertical-alignment

Can someone provide me with a way to create vertical tabs using React?

I experimented with various npm packages like react-web-tabs,reactstrap and react-bootstrap.The last two only had examples for horizontal tabs.React-web-tabs has a vertical tab example in their docs but it doesn't work.

```js
import { Tabs, Tab, TabPanel, TabList } from 'react-web-tabs';

class NewNavigation extends React.Component{
render(){
return(
    <Tabs defaultTab="vertical-tab-one" vertical>
        <TabList>
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-one">Tab 1</Tab>
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-two">Tab 2</Tab>
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-three">Tab 3</Tab>
        </TabList>

        <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-one">
            <p>Tab 1 content</p>
        </TabPanel>

        <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-two">
            <p>Tab content</p>
        </TabPanel>

        <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-three">
            <p>Tab 3 content</p>
        </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
    );
}
}
```

By now, it displays basic horizontal tabs and I want to fix this code as it displays vertical tabs.It is also highly appreciated if you recommend any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding following CSS will do the trick for you:

```css
.rwt__tab  {
  width: 100%
}
```

Another way is to import the CSS file in your component by adding the following line:

```css
import 'react-web-tabs/dist/react-web-tabs.css';
```

Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wo70qkvyq7) if for your reference.

Comment: Can confirm that `import 'react-web-tabs/dist/react-web-tabs.css';` works -> https://codesandbox.io/s/k0vl530k97