# How to create vertical tab using reactjs and css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Am trying to bulid vertical tab that will function exactly like in the demo link below
[sample links from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_vertical_tabs)

here is the screenshot of what am trying to achieve as per the demo sample above
[image: demo sample screenshot]

To this effect tried solution found here at but it does not give me what I want as per demo sample above
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960066/how-to-make-vertical-tabs-with-react)

Now I have decided to go my own way in trying it out.

I have succeeded in displaying the content from an array via reactjs. when user click on each country, the content
of that country gets displayed.

**My Problem:**

My issue is that I cannot get it to display the content in a vertical tab div as can be seen in the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

**Here is the coding so far**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Country extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };
  toggleOpen = id => {
    alert(id);

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      open: !prevState.open
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button onClick={() => this.toggleOpen(this.props.data.id)}>
            {this.props.data.name}
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          {this.state.open && (
            <div>
              <div>
                <b>id: </b>
                {this.props.data.id}
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Info: </b>
                {this.props.data.info}
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Country name:</b> {this.props.data.name}
              </div>
              content for <b> {this.props.data.name}</b> will appear here..
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class VerticalTab extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "London", info: "London is the capital city of England." },
        { id: "2", name: "Paris", info: "Paris is the capital of France." },
        { id: "3", name: "Tokyo", info: "Tokyo is the capital of Japan." }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map(country => (
            <Country key={country.id} data={country} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          currentTab: -1,
          data: [
            { id: "1", name: "London" ,info: "London is the capital city of England."},
            { id: "2", name: "Paris" ,info: "Paris is the capital of France." },
            { id: "3", name: "Tokyo"  ,info: "Tokyo is the capital of Japan."}
          ]
  };
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(currentTab) {
    this.setState({ currentTab });
  }
    
  render() {
    return (

<div>
  <h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
  <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
  <div className="tab">
  {this.state.data.map((button, i) => (
    <button key={button.name} className="tablinks" onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>{button.name}</button>
    )
    )
  }
  </div>

  <div className="tabcontent">
    {this.state.currentTab !== -1 &&
      <React.Fragment>
        <h3>{this.state.data[this.state.currentTab].name}</h3>
        <p>{this.state.data[this.state.currentTab].info}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  </div>
</div>
  )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: This does not attempt to explain the solution.

Comment: @Hamed, Thanks for your contribution so far. This exactly what I want. Just one issue with the solution.  Assuming I have 195 countries in the array, it will not be good to create 195 onclick button. Is there no way to loop through the array using map() method to get handleclick() function for each country. Between thanks so far

Comment: @NancyMooree I updated the code and add a map function. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sir Hamed. Am accepting your answer. You are the best. Just one final wish from you. The app display londons records on page load. how do i prevent that. please can you provide an alternate answer. what if I only want to be displaying records on each button click. Thanks so much. hoping to hear from you Sir

Comment: @NancyMooree Thanks. I updated to code to prevent displaying London records on page load. Sorry, I didn't get the second part of comment.

Comment: Thanks alot Sir Hamed. Remain blessed. Am upvoting your answer as the best in the world

Comment: @NancyMooree Haha Thanks Nancy. Glad it helped.

Comment: Hi Sir Hamed, Please am having issues here. can you help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032662/how-to-hide-and-unhide-images-inside-a-toggled-records-using-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

[Codepen of React Tabs with Hooks](https://codepen.io/ovi/pen/wvPKNer?editors=0110)

JS :

```
import React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

function App() {
  const types = ["tab-1", "tab-2", "tab-3", "tab-4"];
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(types[0]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="tabs">
        <div className="tabs-nav">
          {types.map((type) => (
            <div
              className={`${active === type ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item"}`}
              id={type}
              key={type}
              onClick={() => setActive(type)}
            >
              {type}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="tabs-content">
          {active === "tab-1" && <div className="tab-1"> Tab 1 content </div>}
          {active === "tab-2" && <div className="tab-2"> Tab 2 content </div>}
          {active === "tab-3" && <div className="tab-3"> Tab 3 content </div>}
          {active === "tab-4" && <div className="tab-4"> Tab 4 content </div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Merienda", cursive;
}

.tabs {
    padding: 10px;
    .tabs-nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

      .nav-item {
        color: #000000;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: color 0.5s linear;
      }
      .active {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #00d0ab;
        color: #00d0ab;
        transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -o-transition: color 0.5s linear;
        -moz-transition: color 0.5s linear;
      }
    }
    .tabs-content {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  }
```