# ReactJS: How to hide/unhide images inside toggled list items

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented a React component that lists records, and allows records to be toggled (hidden and unhidden) via a `<button>` element.

I now need to toggle/hiding/unhide the image of each list item, via a separate switch/button that is present for each list item:

[image: screenshot]

I currently have this code to toggle the display of images per list item:

```
  hideUnhidePhoto(id) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, photoVisible: !item.photoVisible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }
```

And, I have this `<a>` anchor element that allows the image display to be controlled via click event:

```
<a style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={this.hideUnhidePhoto.bind(this, post.id)}>
Hide/Unhide Photo
</a>
```

**The problem:**

My issue is that each time I click on Hide/Unhide Photo button, rather than toggling the display of just the photo, clicking this button causes all the items in my list to hide:

**My attempt:**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class Focus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      shown: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title", image: "http://localhost/1.png", visible: true , photoVisible: true},
        { id: "2", title: "my second title", image: "http://localhost/2.png", visible: true, photoVisible: true},
        { id: "3", title: "my third title", image: "http://localhost/3.png", visible: true, photoVisible: true}
      ]
    });
  }


  toggle(id) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, visible: !item.visible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }





  hideUnhidePhoto(id) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, photoVisible: !item.photoVisible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                <div style={{ display: post.visible ? "none" : "block"}}> 

<b>Post Data:</b> {post.title} --{post.id}   <br />

<a style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={this.hideUnhidePhoto.bind(this, post.id)}> Hide/Unhide Photo </a><br />

<div style={{ display: post.visible1 ? "none" : "block"}}> 

<img src={post.image} />

</div>

</div>
                <button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, post.id)}>Toggle ({post.id}) </button>
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then it looks like there are a few small mistakes in your render function, namely this:

```
style={{ display: post.visible1 ? "none" : "block"}}
```

From what I can see, there is no `visible1` field on your `post` items, which will cause unexpected behaviour for your image toggling. You might consider revising your `render()` function a detailed by the comments bellow:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <label>
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <div style={{ display: post.visible ? "none" : "block"}}> 
                <b>Post Data:</b> {post.title} -- {post.id}   <br />

                { /* Revise event handler binding with arrow function as shown. 
                Also consider a change from <a> to something like <span> to ensure 
                no default click behavour on <a> happens if href were added */ }
                <span style={{color: 'red'}} 
                      onClick={ () => this.hideUnhidePhoto(post.id) }>
                Hide/Unhide Photo
                </span>

                <br />

                {/* Update image display to be controlled via post.photoVisible 
                field */ }
                <div style={{ display: post.photoVisible ? "block" : "none"}}> 
                    <img src={post.image} />
                </div>
            </div>
            { /* I prefer to use arrow functions in general to make the code 
            a little more readable */ }
            <button onMouseDown={ () => this.toggle(post.id) }>Toggle ({post.id}) </button>
            <br />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </label>
  </div>
);
}
```

Also, consider revising your `hideUnhidePhoto()` method like so, to ensure that mapped data for evey `item` is cloned:

```
hideUnhidePhoto(id) {

    this.setState(({ data }) => {
        return { 
            data : data.map(item => ({ 
            ...item, 
            photoVisible : (id == item.id) ? !item.photoVisible : item.photoVisible }))
        }
    });
}
```

### Update

Here's a working JSFiddle demonstrating the solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lvyw5u4q/1/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Sir Dacre for your contribution so far. I have implemented your solution but still having issues. For instance if am on the first toggled records, When I toggle the Image button inside it. instead of only image to hide/unhide, it will just close all the records for that toggled button

Comment: Not yet Sir, It shows error  
bundle.js:98745 Uncaught ReferenceError: photoVisible is not defined

Comment: Thank You Sir,The error is gone. this is issues Now if open toggle1 and click on  button for image  inside togge1 record, it will close the toggle1 instead of hiding/unhide the image.  If open toggle2 and click on image button, it will open toggle and Toggle2 etc. I think there is an Id issues between parent toggle and child (image toggle). Am still thanking you for your effort so far. still counting on your help sir

Comment: Ok - realised what the issue is. It seems, by chance, that the click event is triggering on both the button and the span (due to the hiding of the image, causing the button to be placed under the cursor) One solution would be to use `onMouseDown` to prevent the "collision" as shown above - hope that helps!

Comment: Thank You Sir Dacre. I appreciate. Please I have another issue in new post. please can you see it to help. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036609/how-to-display-three-post-photo-div-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-using-reactjs-and

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to include a style of display property inside your constructor function and trigger this with your trigger function

inside constructor function of your class

> this.mystyle= {
> display: "none"
> };

give image this style by

> img src="..." alt="..." style={this.mystyle} /

toggle the image by this type of code

> this.mystyle={display:'inline'};