# How to display three post photo div at the bottom of the page using Reactjs and Css

Tags: css, reactjs

The code below has three posts photos in the array. When I click on each post button am supposed to be seeing
Three post Photo div that corresponds to each post all at the bottom.

**My Problem:**

My issue is that it is showing just one post photo div which keeps replacing others after I  added the CSS code below.

```
const mainArea={
 position: 'fixed',
  width: '80%',
  bottom: '0%',
   display: 'inline-block'
}

const photodiv={
position: 'relative',
width: '250px',
  // height:auto,
  background: 'orange',
  color: 'black',
  borderRadius: '5px 5px 0px 0px',
  bottom: '0px',

}
```

**screenshot showing jammed div based on the CSS implementation**

[image: screenshot showing jamed div based on css implementation]

**What I want:**
I need to be seeing three div post photos if the three toggle button is clicked

**Here is the main code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const mainArea={
 position: 'fixed',
  width: '80%',
  bottom: '0%',
   display: 'inline-block'
}

const photodiv={
position: 'relative',
width: '250px',
  // height:auto,
  background: 'orange',
  color: 'black',
  borderRadius: '5px 5px 0px 0px',
  bottom: '0px',

}

class Focus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      shown: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title", image: "http://localhost/apidb_react/1.png", visible: true , photoVisible: true},
        { id: "2", title: "my second title", image: "http://localhost/apidb_react/2.png", visible: true, photoVisible: true},
        { id: "3", title: "my third title", image: "http://localhost/apidb_react/3.png", visible: true, photoVisible: true}
      ]
    });
  }


  toggle(id) {
    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, visible: !item.visible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }




/*

  hideUnhidePhoto(id) {

    const newData = this.state.data.map(item => {

alert(id);

      if(item.id === id) {
alert('ttto  ' +item.id);
        return { ...item, photoVisible: !item.photoVisible};
      }

      return item;
    })

    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  }
*/



hideUnhidePhoto(id) {

    this.setState(({ data }) => {
        return { 
            data : data.map(item => ({ 
            ...item, 
            photoVisible : (id == item.id) ? !item.photoVisible : item.photoVisible }))
        }
    });
}



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>

<div style={mainArea}>
<div style={photodiv}>
                <div style={{ display: post.visible ? "none" : "block"}}> 

<b>Post Data:</b> {post.title} --{post.id}   <br />

<span style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={ () => this.hideUnhidePhoto(post.id) }> Hide/Unhide Photo</span>

<div style={{ display: post.photoVisible ? "block" : "none"}}> 

<img src={post.image} />

</div>

</div></div>
</div>
 <button onMouseDown={ () => this.toggle(post.id) }>Toggle </button><br />


                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }







}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, then this can be fixed by adjusting your `mainArea` style object like so:

```
const mainArea={
  /* position: 'fixed', Remove position fixed */
  width: '80%',
  bottom: '0%',
  display: 'inline-block'
}
```

The [`fixed` position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) basically has the effect of placing elements at a location on screen, relative to the client area of the window. This means that if you have multiple elements that share the same (default) coordinates, and are positioned with the `fixed` rule, then those elements will effectively overlap one another. This gives the appearance of only one element being visible at any given time.

For a working example, see this jsFiddle:
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/y1kc7xzv/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot Sir Dacre